# how to check multiple values in a single comma seperated column

Tags: c#, sql, select

I am trying to execute a query in c#,the query as

`select Id from employee where name in (@name)`

i am try to passing 3 cases

```
1.@name='sa'
2.@name='as,ab'
3.@name='ad'
```

> and the output am expecting
>
> 1.id=1
>
> 2.id=2
>
> 3.id=3

my table employee value contains ,

[image]

Comment: You should not store CSV data in a column like that. There should be a separate table with records like `an` and `sa` and then a third table that joins the two tables.

Comment: `as` and `an` check boxes values so i can select multiple checkbox `as` and `an` so the date saved by table as ,as,an

Comment: i mean that the issue not realated to database but i connected a db for  executing this into c#

Comment: I would argue it is related to database. Your database model is poor (as per my first comment).

Comment: can't you convert a to a list

Answer (score 0):

First create user defined split function in DB using this [link](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Split-function-in-SQL-Server-Example-Function-to-Split-Comma-separated-Delimited-string-in-SQL-Server-2005-2008-and-2012.aspx) Then Apply to your table. it would very easy for you.

Answer (score -1):

How about the assigning the  variable

```
@name='%sa%'
```

and then using this below query

```
 select * from employee where Names LIKE (@name)
```